Extending Special Automorphisms of Lie Manifolds
I call a smooth manifold $M$ special if it is diffeomorphic to a connected Lie group $G_M$ of automorphisms of $M$.
Let $M$ be a special smooth manifold and $N$ a special smooth submanifold of $M$. $G_N$ is some connected Lie group of automorphisms that makes $N$ special. Can every automorphism in $G_N$ be extended to an automorphism of $M$?
It does not have to be unique, I am just interested in whether there exists an automorphism of $M$ that matches any automorphism in $G_N$ when restricted to $N$.
(This is a follow-up question to Extending Diffeomorphisms of Lie Manifolds)

Do you assume that $N$ is properly embedded in $M$?

@MoisheKohan yes

I will assume that $N$ is properly embedded in $N$, otherwise the claim fails even in the case when $M=\mathbb R$ and $N=(0,1)$. The key is that $G_N$ is connected and, hence, every element of $G_N$ corresponds to a diffeomorphism $f: N\to N$ smoothly isotopic to the identity. Let $f_t, t\in [0,1]$ denote the isotopy. Now, you apply the isotopy extension theorem (see for instance M.Hirsch, "Differential Topology") to extend the entire isotopy $f_t$ to an isotopy via diffeomorphisms $g_t: M\to M, t\in [0,1]$. Briefly, the extension works as follows. Let $X_t$ denote the time-dependent vector-field on $N$ such that $d_t(f_t)(p)=X(p)$, $p\in N, t\in [0,1]$. Then extend $X$ to a time-dependent vector field $Y_t$ on $N$ and define the isotopy $g_t$ by
$$
d_t(g_t)(q)=Y(q), q\in M, t\in [0,1].
$$
The vector field $Y_t$ has to be chosen carefully to avoid problems with incompleteness. Consider a tubular neighborhood $U$ of $N$ in $M$. For simplicity of the notation, I will assume that $U=N\times D^k$, where $D^k$ is an open $k$-disk and $k$ is the codimension of $N$ in $M$. (In general, $U$ has structure of a $D^k$-bundle over $N$, I am not sure you know what this means.) Let $\phi$ be a bump-function on $D^k$ such that $\phi(0)=1$ and $\phi$ has compact support in $D^k$. Now, take
$$
Y_t(p, z):= (\phi(z) X_t(p), 0), z\in D^k
$$
and $Y_t$ is identically zero on $M\setminus U$. One then verifies that the equation $d_t(g_t)(q)=Y(q)$ has a smooth solution for all $q\in M, t\in [0,1]$ with the initial condition $g_0(q)=q, q\in M$.
